# Console logging imported SVGs gives numbers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

When I import an SVG and passe it to another component as props and console.log the passed SVG prop I get numbers. I am running into issues due to this because the `react-native-svg-uri` requires me to import the SVG as  a string for its `svgXmlData` property.

**Parent Component**

```
import SVGICON from './icon.svg';

const ParentComponent = () => {
  console.log(SVGICON); // this outputs numbers
  return (
    <ChildComponent
      icon={SVGICON}
    />
  );
};
```

**Child Component**

```
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri'

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <SvgUri
      width="24"
      height="24"
      svgXmlData={props.icon}
    />
  );
};
```

However I also noticed that when i import the icon in the same place as the 
SvgUri it renders properly and console.log renders the proper svg components as a string.

**Sometimes this works but I am not sure why**

```
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';
import SVGICON from './icon.svg';

const WorkingComponent = () => {
  return (
    <SvgUri
      width="24"
      height="24"
      svgXmlData={SVGICON}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: `svgXmlData={props.icon * 1}` or `Number(props.icon)` Could you try this? Conversion allows you to try to solve the problem.

Comment: @hongdevelop I dont want it to log as numbers I want it to be the SVG component itself.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can pass filename as prop and load file dynamically in child component.
I have a similar component in which i load svg icon like below:
 ``` logo = require(``./icons/${props.icon}.svg``) ```